# Undefined values getting after service call in angular2 application

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have service which returns an observable with specified class type which does an http request to my server and gets the data.I want to use this data but I always end up getting undefined. What's the problem?

**Service.ts**

```
 @Injectable()
    export class ToDoListClient {
    private http: Http;
    private baseUrl: string;
    protected jsonParseReviver: (key: string, value: any) => any = undefined;

    constructor(@Inject(Http) http: Http, @Optional() @Inject(API_BASE_URL) baseUrl?: string) {
        this.http = http;
        this.baseUrl = baseUrl ? baseUrl : "";
    }

    get(): Observable<ToDoItem[]> {
        let url_ = this.baseUrl + "/api/ToDoList";
        url_ = url_.replace(/[?&]$/, "");

        let options_ = {
            method: "get",
            headers: new Headers({
                "Content-Type": "application/json", 
                "Accept": "application/json"
            })
        };

        return this.http.request(url_, options_).flatMap((response_) => {
            return this.processGet(response_);
        }).catch((response_: any) => {
            if (response_ instanceof Response) {
                try {
                    return this.processGet(response_);
                } catch (e) {
                    return <Observable<ToDoItem[]>><any>Observable.throw(e);
                }
            } else
                return <Observable<ToDoItem[]>><any>Observable.throw(response_);
        });
    }

    protected processGet(response: Response): Observable<ToDoItem[]> {
        const status = response.status; 

        if (status === 200) {
            const _responseText = response.text();
            let result200: ToDoItem[] = null;
            let resultData200 = _responseText === "" ? null : JSON.parse(_responseText, this.jsonParseReviver);
            if (resultData200 && resultData200.constructor === Array) {
                result200 = [];
                for (let item of resultData200)
                    result200.push(ToDoItem.fromJS(item));
            }
            return Observable.of(result200);
        } else if (status !== 200 && status !== 204) {
            const _responseText = response.text();
            return throwException("An unexpected server error occurred.", status, _responseText);
        }
        return Observable.of<ToDoItem[]>(<any>null);
     }

    }
```

**Component.ts**

```
public toDoItems: ToDoItem[];
 ngOnInit() {
    console.log('TodoComponent');
    this.populate();
}
/* get ToDoItems */
populate() {

//let config = { headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + this.msalService.access_token } };
this.toDoListClient.get().subscribe(
    (response) =>  {
        this.toDoItems = response;
         console.log(this.toDoItems); ---> here printing the undefined values.
     },function (err: any) {
    this.error = err;       
      });
   };
```

**Console Output:**

[image]

The above code didn't work properly, when I am trying to get the list of data from my server. it just returns number of records from server with undefined fields values like above image.

Comment: most probably your `.map` does't return response

Comment: The Services.ts file generated by NSwag based on web api swagger Json data.

Comment: I am getting the list of count value but in the list of all values will be undefined. Can you please any one tell me how to resolve my issue as soon as possible?

Comment: according to console image data is not coming from the backend side, you have to debug your code on the server side not on the client side i mean to say in angular side

Comment: My server returns data with exact values what I needed . I think the issue in typescript code.

Comment: yes, it can be possible, if so than for sure error is in your `processGet` method where you push into array, try simply by returning same array which you get from backend, also try to console there. you will get your error easily.